# CI_Doctrinre not found in hmvc codeigniter3

Tags: php, codeigniter, doctrine-orm, codeigniter-3, hmvc

I am using HMVC CI3 and I have a MY_Contrller in core which extends MX_Controller. now, I have a module called orm and I am extending this class like as follows,

```
class Orm extends CI_Controller
{
    private $st;
    private $cmf;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->st = new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\SchemaTool($this->doctrine->em);
        $this->cmf = $this->doctrine->em->getMetadataFactory();
        $this->cmf->setEntityManager($this->doctrine->em);

        $this->module = 'orm';
        $this->controller = 'orm';
    }


    public function index()
    {
        $realm = 'Restricted area for ORM Controller of NibsRMS';


        $this->load->view("orm");
    }
}
```

when I run this in browser, it shows me the following error

**Fatal error: Class 'CI_Doctrine' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\tiffintom_master\system\core\Common.php on line 196**

Comment: Your title says CI_Controller not found. Your post says CI_Doctrine not found. Which one is it, please?

Comment: thanks, I have changed my title

Comment: Hi If your using HMVC then the CI_Controller should be MX_Controller

Comment: but I dont want to use MX_Controller for only this module of controller